# oAuth2 grant_type issues Curl vs Postman

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am trying to get a token from the AAD service for authentication purposes.

Postman works when I have

```
Grant_Type="Client_credentials", 
Token URL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXX/oauth2/v2.0/token",
Clinet_ID="XXXX",
Client_Secret="xxxx",
Scope="https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

But curl doesn't work for the same values in the following command

```
curl --request POST \
--url 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
--header 'content-type: application/json' \
--data '{"grant_type":"client_credentials","client_id": "XXXXXX","client_secret": "XXXXXXX"\, 
"scope": "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
```

I am getting the following error

> "error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS900144: The request body must enter code here`contain the enter >code here`following parameter:enter code here`'grant_type'

Need Help

Answer (score 1):

Use curl with this form of command:

```
curl --request POST \
--url 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=XXXXXXXXX' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=XXXXXXXXX' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' \
--verbose
```